# Strange C error while freeing memory?

Tags: c, free, pointer-to-pointer

I'm still trying to get my genetic algorithm to work (yesterday I had a problem with memory allocation and consequently an awful error when attempting to free it) but today I have this piece of code

```
while (iCurrentGen <= data->m_iMaxGenerations)
{
    arrfSelectedChromosomes = selection(&data[0], szChromosomes);
    iSelectedLen = order_descending_grid(arrfSelectedChromosomes);
    szAuxGen = crossover(&data[0], arrfSelectedChromosomes, szChromosomes, iSelectedLen);
    //szChromosomes is what I need to free after that call returns
    free_generation(&data[0], szChromosomes);//Code Explotion
    szChromosomes = szAuxGen;
    szAuxGen = NULL;
    ++iCurrentGen;
}
```

I was checking its content before the `free_generation()` function call and It was something like the picture below:

(Variable first four values)

[image: Variable first four values]

But inside the `free_generation()` function, the same variable loses some of its values (specifically when `i` takes value 2, `i` being the for loop index), as shown below:

(Variable values inside the function)

[image: Variable values inside the function]

I post the free_generation code below:

```
void free_generation(struct INPUT_DATA* d, char** szChromosomes)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
    {
        free(szChromosomes[i]);
    }

    free(szChromosomes);
    szChromosomes = NULL;
}
```

The definition of `szChromosomes` is as follows:

```
char** szChromosomes = (char**)malloc(d->m_iPopulationSize * sizeof(char*));

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; ++i)
{
    szChromosomes[i] = (char*)malloc((d->m_iBitsPChromosome + 1) * sizeof(char));
    for (j = 0; j < d->m_iBitsPChromosome; ++j)
    {
        szChromosomes[i][j] = rand_1_0(0.0, 1.0) == 1? '1' : '0';
    }
    szChromosomes[i][j] = '\0';
}
```

I need to clarify that this value's loss occurs only after the second iteration of the while loop posted on top. I mean on the first run everything works perfectly but after this iteration, the second one behaves as described above.

EDIT:

I forgot to include the increment of the loop control variable (thanks for pointing that out! and no, it isn't global xD). I'm including parts of the crossover code:

```
    char** crossover(struct INPUT_DATA* d, float** arrfSelectedChromosomes, char** arrszChromosomes, int iChromosomesInGrid)
{
    int i;
    int iTIndex = 0, iRPos = 0;
    char* szFirstChromosome = NULL;
    char* szSecondChromosome = NULL;
    char* szFirstNewChrom = (char*)malloc((d->m_iBitsPChromosome + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char* szSecondNewChrom = (char*)malloc((d->m_iBitsPChromosome + 1) * sizeof(char));

    char** arrszNewPop = (char**)malloc(d->m_iPopulationSize * sizeof(char*));

    int iSplitPoint = (int)(d->m_iBitsPChromosome / 4);

    float fCrossOverProb = CROSSOVER_PROBABILITY; 

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < d->m_iPopulationSize; i += 2)
    {
        iRPos = rand() % iChromosomesInGrid;
        iTIndex = (int)arrfSelectedChromosomes[iRPos][0];
        szFirstChromosome = arrszChromosomes[iTIndex];
        iRPos =  rand() % iChromosomesInGrid;
        iTIndex = (int)arrfSelectedChromosomes[iRPos][0];
        szSecondChromosome = arrszChromosomes[iTIndex];

        if (is_same_chromosome(szFirstChromosome, szSecondChromosome))
        {
            i -= 2;
            continue;
        }

        if (fCrossOverProb < CROSSOVER_PROBABILITY)
        {
            //if probability is lower than the defined prob. we keep both chromosomes
            strcpy(szFirstNewChrom, szFirstChromosome);
            strcpy(szSecondNewChrom, szSecondChromosome);
        }
        else
        {

            strcpy(szFirstNewChrom, szFirstChromosome);
            szFirstNewChrom[iSplitPoint] = '\0';
            strcat(szFirstNewChrom, &szSecondChromosome[iSplitPoint]);

            //Para crear el segundo hijo se realiza una operacion similar
            strcpy(szSecondNewChrom, szSecondChromosome);
            szSecondNewChrom[iSplitPoint] = '\0';
            strcat(szSecondNewChrom, &szFirstChromosome[iSplitPoint]);
        }

        arrszNewPop[i] = szFirstNewChrom;
        arrszNewPop[i + 1] = szSecondNewChrom;
    }

    return arrszNewPop;
}
```

Comment: If you are running under Linux or MacOS/X, try installing valgrind and running your program under that.   It may show you where things are going wrong.

Comment: Your chromosomes array contains duplicated pointer values. Once you use `free` on the same pointer twice, all hell breaks loose. Incidentally, this happens at iteration 3 (i==2). You need to trace how these duplicated values ended up in the array.

Comment: I'm under windows Jeremy.. Can the duplicated pointer value occur because of call to strcat like this:

strcpy(szFirstNewChrom, szFirstChromosome);
szFirstNewChrom[iSplitPoint] = '\0';
strcat(szFirstNewChrom, &szSecondChromosome[iSplitPoint]);

iSplitPoint is an int between 0 and 31.. I'm a creating a new chromosome with the concatenation of two chromosomes. szFirstNewChrom allocates 33 bytes before being used

Comment: How does `crossover()` actually *work* ?? Furthermore, I see no modifications to the loop control variable `iCurrentGen` in your `while()` loop, so obviously that isn't all the code that is executing (unless, of course, it is a global, which would be a terrible design).

Comment: Dupe pointers is the result of copying (assigning) pointers themselves, not pointed-to characters. Single-step the program and watch the chromosomes array.

Comment: I modified my question. Thanks WhozCraig

Comment: n.m You're the man! thanks so much.. It was a problem of duplicated pointers, and it was due to wrong memory allocation in crossover function. I was allocating memory for szFirstNewChrom and szSecondNewChrom at the beginning of the function but that memory was used for 30 different strings. Because of that terrible mistake, the free_generation function kept failing since it was trying to free a pointer freed previously. Thank you all!

Comment: And don't forget to remove all the casts from the malloc() returns. They're useless and potentially hide errors (not #including <stdlib.h>).

Comment: `while (iCurrentGen <= data->m_iMaxGenerations)` Is suspect. Dit you mean `while (iCurrentGen < data->m_iMaxGenerations)` ? Hint: use a for-loop instead of `++iCurrentGen;` at the end of the loop-body. ( I know that `iCurrentGen` is never referenced inside the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

n.m You're the man! thanks so much.. It was a problem of duplicated pointers, and it was due to wrong memory allocation in crossover function. I was allocating memory for szFirstNewChrom and szSecondNewChrom at the beginning of the function but that memory was used for 30 different strings. Because of that terrible mistake, the free_generation function kept failing since it was trying to free a pointer freed previously. Thank you all! –  Jorge Cespedes